# Declaring vs defining variables in c

Tags: c, variables, definition, variable-declaration

As I know this is a declaration:

```
int i;
```

and this is a definition:

```
int i = 10;
```

May be I am wrong I don't argue.

**The question is** Does the compiler set aside memory for the declared (but not defined) variables?

Comment: Somewhat related, when you define a symbol which haven't been declared yet, you both declare and define the symbol.

Comment: C has the concept of [tentative definition](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.2).

Comment: Both lines are declarations. Both can be definitions (and usually are).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the compiler set aside memory for the declared (but not defined)
>   variables?

No, compiler just take a note of this variable name and type. No memory is allocated for declaration.

`int i;` can behave as definition if `i` is used (not optimized out) and [no other definition](http://ideone.com/nNy1fu) of `i` is present in any other compilation unit and storage will be reserved for it. (because storage is reserved for definitions)

Answer (score 4):

Definition is when storage is allocated for a variable. Declaration does not imply storage has been allocated yet.

A declaration is used in order to access functions or variables defined in different source files, or in a library. A mismatch between the definition type and the declaration type generates a compiler error.

Here are some examples of declarations that are not definitions, in C:

```
extern char example1;
extern int example2;
void example3(void);
```

From the [C standard (n1256)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **6.7 Declarations**
> ...
> 5 A declaration specifies the interpretation and attributes of a set of identifiers. 
>
>
> A ***definition*** of an identifier is a declaration for that identifier that:
>
> — for an object, causes storage to be reserved for that object;
>
> — for a function, includes the function body;<sup>101)</sup>
> — for an enumeration constant or typedef name, is the (only) declaration of the
> identifier.

Comment: And that of course implies that *both* lines of code in the question can be definitions.

Answer (score 3):

> *"Does the compiler set aside memory for the declared (but not defined) variables?"*

No. Compiler only allocates memory for (at time of) variable definition, not on variable declaration.

You can better understand the logic using a simple analogy, multiple declaration is allowed for a single variable, but multiple definition is not.